# Multiple WHEN inside no-expression CASE in SQL?

Tags: sql, case

```
    DECLARE @TestVal int
SET @TestVal = 5

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @TestVal <=3 THEN 'Top 3'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END
```

I saw this sample code online but I couldn't find an example where there was no expression and it had more than one WHEN, so I am wondering if this type of thing is OK:

```
    DECLARE @TestVal int
SET @TestVal = 5

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @TestVal <=3 THEN 'Top 3'
                WHEN (select ...) = 1 THEN 'Other Value'
                WHEN (select ...) = 2 THEN 'Other Value 2'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END
```

Or do I need to say CASE WHEN for each line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) takes the following form

```
CASE WHEN Condition THEN Result
     WHEN Condition2 THEN Result2
ELSE Default
END
```

## Edit

This assumes your using Microsoft SQL Server other DBMS might be different

Answer (score 7):

Yes, that's fine, but I would line up the "WHEN"s vertically and explain it more like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @TestVal <=3  THEN 'Top 3'
        WHEN @TestVal <=10 THEN 'Top 10'
        WHEN @TestVAl <=25 THEN 'Top 25'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END
```

The formatting might just be a markdown glitch, but the `(select...)` in your example complicated what should be a simpler snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
       CASE
          WHEN @TestVal <=3  THEN 'Top 3'
          WHEN @TestVal <=10 THEN 'Top 10'
          WHEN @TestVAl <=25 THEN 'Top 25'
          ELSE 'Other'
       END
```

In regards to nesting case statements this can be done as well (up until 10 nested case statements allowed within sql)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx